# Trying to restrict an Eloquent query to a relationship with a count of 0

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have two models (Organizations and Interactions) and I'd like to query the Organization model for all of the Orgs that have no Interactions. Organizations have a one-to-many relationship with Interactions.

I tried looking into anti-joins in raw SQL, but got nowhere. I also wanted to totally avoid anything like getting all of the full Organizations, then iterating through them to check to see if they had any Interactions, because that's completely impractical given the amount of data I'm working with.

To clarify, I want to **avoid** this:

```
$organizations = Organization::all();
foreach ($organizations as $org)
    if($org->interactions()->count() == 0){
        //Add the org to an array for later use because it has no interactions
    }
```

I'm using Laravel 3.x, and I can't upgrade because the project is really big and I don't have the month it would take to upgrade to 4.1 right now. If there's a significantly better way to do stuff like this 4, that would make selling the conversion process easier.

Here's some relevant code:

```
//From organization.php
public function interactions() {
     return $this->has_many('Interaction');
}


//From interaction.php
public function organization() {
     return $this->belongs_to('Organization');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

// select all Organization IDs that have at least 1 interaction

```
$uniqueOrganizationIDs = DB::raw('SELECT organization_id FROM interactions GROUP BY(organization_id)');
```

// Select orgs that were not in the above list.

```
Organization::whereNotIn('id', $uniqueOrganizationIDs)->get();
```

Comment: This sounds like the most efficient way of doing it (not sure if whereNotIn is in Laravel 3). Only two queries like mine, but no need to loop through the array.

Comment: Thanks. WhereNotIn is exactly what I was looking for. In L3, it's where_not_in, but the arguments are the same.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I came up with:

1. Query the Organization and Interaction models using `list()`. For Orgs, get their ID. For Interactions, get their organization_id. I figure these are two low-footprint, fast queries.
2. Do an `array_diff()` on them to get an array of Organizations that don't have Interactions.
3. Query Organization using `where_in()`, feeding it the diff'ed array.

It looks like this:

```
 $organizationIDs = DB::table('organizations')->where('is_deleted', '=', 0)->lists('id');

 $interactionIDs = DB::table('interactions')where('is_deleted', '=', 0)->lists('organization_id');

 $uncontactedOrganizationIDs = array_diff($organizationIDs, $interactionIDs);

 $uncontactedOrganizations = Organization::where_in('id', $uncontactedOrganizationIDs)->order_by('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
```

Is there a better way to do this? I feel like there has to be.